# Are the exercise and fitness tags meta-tags?

Tags: discussion

Are the [exercise](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercise) and [fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitness) tags like the cooking tag on Cooking.SE (i.e. [useless meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/))?

I can see a point to the  [nutrition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) tag: if this site is meant to cover the [Nutrition proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15687/nutrition), then dietitians and nutritionists will want to filter the non-nutrition question (and those uninterested in nutrition can add it to their ignored tags). Exercise and fitness, however, seem a bit too vague for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think they are ineffective, redundant tags.

There are two types of tags which are *explicitly* discouraged: redundant tags and meta-tags.

**Redundant** tags are those that are already *implied* by the site topic. There's simply no value to tags like [exercise], [fitness], [health], etc. Even the [nutrition] tag has limited value. Efforts to coarsely sub-divide the site like that will fail. Tags are not meant (nor well-suited) for the task of dividing the entire site into large swaths for the purpose of participating in (or ignoring) a broad subject site-wide.

**Meta-tags** are a problem because they do not tell you what the question is about. They describe something like:

- The author's motivation for asking the question (stupid, funny, quackery, etc)
- What *kind* of question is being asked (subjective, poll, request, etc)

Each tag should be able to stand on its own to tell you what the question is about. For example: the tag "subjective", taken alone, doesn't tell you *anything* about what the question is about. If it cannot pass that acid test, remove it.

See: [**The Death of Meta Tags**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)