# Should exercise tag really be a synonym of exercises

Tags: discussion

I tried to tag my question with exercises, however this tag was replaced by the exercise tag.

I'm not sure if it's the same in other countries, but in Australia, exercise refers to any general activity that increases the heart rate e.g. swimming, football and running are all types of exercise.

However, push-ups, sit-ups, squats etc. are exercises.

If this is the case in other countries I suggest that exercises not be a synonym of exercise as they are not the same.

If exercise is removed as a meta tag per [this question](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/are-the-exercise-and-fitness-tags-meta-tags). I suggest we definitely have an exercises tag so that people can find questions that are purely about doing those types of exercises (push-ups etc.).

Maybe fitness trainers have some other more specific way to refer to exercises? If this is the case then please just suggest this to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the term exercises (the way you are using it) is still far too broad. Additionally, it will likely get confused and re-used as the current "exercise" tag is, creating a larger mess.

Consider using the proper word "[calisthenics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calisthenics)" to define push-ups, sit-ups, etc.

Comment: Great answer, I was looking for the right tag to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually the `exercise` tag is redundant on this site.  Pretty much any post about weight lifting, running, or basketball can be tagged `exercise`, so `exercise` does not add any meaning.

A site user might not think to search `calisthenics` if they're really looking for `exercises`, so I think `exercise` should be phased out and `exercises` should be used as the OP of this question suggests.