# Burninate exercise tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

The question has been [asked before](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/3941), but as the scope of the FAQ changed I am proposing to remove [exercise](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercise) again.

Every question on fitness.SE could be tagged with exercise as the FAQ states that every question should relate to exercise. So there is no real use to this tag.

Other tags that should be burninated, I think they are equivalently useless:

[workout](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workout)

Comment: Questions tagged with workout can (as far as I checked) often be re-tagged to [tag:workout-routine]

Comment: [tag:fitness] has been burninated today, so I removed it from the question.